# Java drawLine command doesn't draw on screen

Tags: java, draw

So I am making a paint program that draws by imputing commands from an IRC server chat room. So everything but the drawing works and I checked it (you can see the checking system out :P) but the drawLine() command doesn't do its thing. Please help!

PS:This is a class file in a project, everything else works sending to here trust me!

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class PadDraw extends JComponent
{
    //this is gonna be your image that you draw on
    Image image;
    //this is what we'll be using to draw on
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
    //these are gonna hold our coordinates
    int currentX = 0, currentY = 0, oldX = 0, oldY = 0;

public PadDraw()
{

}

public void onCommand(String msg)
{
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("up"))
    {

        if(oldY > 0)
        {
            currentY = currentY - 30;
            if(graphics2D != null)
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }
    }
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("down"))
    {
        if(oldY < 861)
        {
            System.out.println(msg);
            System.out.println("Starting Y: " + currentY);
            currentY = currentY + 30;
            System.out.println("Ending Y: " + currentY);
            if(graphics2D != null)
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
            System.out.println("Old Y: " + oldY);
        }
    }
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("left"))
    {
        if(oldX > 0)
        {
            currentX = currentX - 30;
            if(graphics2D != null)
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }
    }
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase("right"))
    {
        if(oldX < 847)
        {
            currentX = currentX + 30;
            if(graphics2D != null){
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            }
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
if(image == null)
{
image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

clear();
}

g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Frankly the code is a bit long and not properly formatted. See if you can do something about it. May help you get more/better answers.

Comment: your code formatting is very difficult to read and does not follow java conventions. please break out each class to their own code window in your post (ie. make sure there is at least 1 or 2 blank lines between the end of one class, and the beginning of the next). If it's easy to read, then you may get faster/better help.

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit going on in your example that doesn't directly relate to your problem (setting up buttons etc.) Try to remove as much as you can from your code until you are left with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. This will both help people here to quickly understand what is going on, and it may also help you figure out the issue yourself.

Comment: Well i made it a lot less now :p

Answer (score 0):

1. You are forgetting to call `super.paintComponent` inside the `paintComponent` method. Some people will wrongly leave it out on purpose thinking its the *right* way to achieve *"continous"* painting, but what you are actually doing is breaking the paint chain, and what you *actually* seeing is paint artifacts, that would lead you to believe there's a continuous paint functionality.
2. The way you are doing it will not produce a *"continous"* painting. For one, you're not even drawing the line to the `JComponent` Graphics context. Second, once you do properly call `super.paintComponent` inside the `paintComponent` method, you will lose an previous painting

### Here's what you *could/should* do, instead...

1. Have a list of `Line2D` objects.

   ```
   List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Loop through the `List` in the `paintComponent` method, and draw them

   ```
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
       ...
       for (Line2D line : lines) {
           g2.draw(line);
       }
   }
   ```

   Oh btw, `paintComponent` should be `protected` and not `public`
3. When ever you want to add a line to the drawing, just add another `Line2D` object to the list and `repaint()`

   ```
   lines.add(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
   repaint();
   ```

---

See more at [Line2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) and [Graphics2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: I am not that great with java yet, so i don't understand much :) So a question here is: 1) where do i put "List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();" like it says "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Line2D>" 2) what does "..." mean?

Comment: You're importing the wrong `List`. There's an AWT component called `java.awt.List`, which is the equivalent of Swing's `JList` and there's a data structure `java.util.List`. You imported the former when you needed the latter.

Comment: Any programming book or tutorial you read, will use the `...` as just saying maybe some code in this place. It's trivial, has no meaning and _should not_ be put into your code. It's just for explaining purposes. In this case, it could mean the other code you have in your `paintComponent` method.

Comment: You think i could get your skype or something so you could help out a bit more? it would be really great! I have noone to ask any help with java at all.

Comment: You have a million people to ask here on SO. The problem is how you ask the question an what you ask. Questions that are too broad are unlikely to get answered. questions with not enough detail describing your problem will not likely get answered. GUI programming related questions are preferred to asked with [a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Other than that, this site is not really a help desk, it's just a Q & A. Most people here are professional and don't really have the time to tutor or mentor. There are tutorials for that...

Comment: ... start with [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Also once you get your rep up to 20, you can use the chat feature on SO. Good luck.